# Adding div Element on d3 Bar Chart

Tags: d3.js

I have a requirement to add div on top of each bar in bar chart using d3. Is it possible to add div instead of adding label. Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a div to your chart and show/hide it, based on condition (for example when a user hovers over the element.

Here is a good [example](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/a22c42db65eb00d4e369) by d3noob.

[image: d3 tooltip]

The useful parts to look for in the code:

1. Define div styles in style tag

```
div.tooltip {   
    position: absolute;         
    text-align: center;         
    width: 60px;                    
    height: 28px;                   
    padding: 2px;               
    font: 12px sans-serif;      
    background: lightsteelblue; 
    border: 0px;        
    border-radius: 8px;         
    pointer-events: none;           
}
```

2. Append div for the tooltip

```
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
    .attr("class", "tooltip")               
    .style("opacity", 0);
```

3. Then show your tooltip on mouseover and hide on mouseout:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {      
    div.transition()        
       .duration(200)       
       .style("opacity", .9);
        
     div.html(formatTime(d.date) + "<br/>"  + d.close)  
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
 })                 
.on("mouseout", function(d) {       
    div.transition()        
       .duration(500)       
       .style("opacity", 0);    
    });
```